# drop records from a df that are not in another df using python

Tags: python, pandas

I've a sample datafram1

```
date           username         cities
2021-03-01     K John           New york
2021-03-01     K John           LA
2021-03-02     Ken Miles        Florida
2021-03-02     Ken Miles        LA
```

dataframe2 contains

```
date          username        planned_cities 
2021-03-01    K John             Alabama
2021-03-02    K John             LA
2021-03-02    Ken Miles          Florida
2021-03-02    Ken Miles          California
```

Expected result (by considering only `date   username`, dropping the columns that are not in df1)

```
date         username        planned_cities
2021-03-01    K John             Alabama
2021-03-02    Ken Miles          Florida
2021-03-02    Ken Miles          California
```

As `2021-03-02   K John` is not in records of df1, it is dropped. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

you could use `Index.isin` with the columns you are interested in and then boolean index:

```
cols = ['date','username']
idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1[cols])
idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df2[cols])
out = df2[idx2.isin(idx1)]
```

---

```
       date   username planned_cities
  2021-03-01     K John        Alabama
  2021-03-02  Ken Miles        Florida
  2021-03-02  Ken Miles     California
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an inner `merge` dropping duplicates that way you ensure you don't grow the left DataFrame.

```
df2.merge(df1[['date', 'username']].drop_duplicates())

         date   username planned_cities
0  2021-03-01     K John        Alabama
1  2021-03-02  Ken Miles        Florida
2  2021-03-02  Ken Miles     California
```